# read file string and store in uint8_t array in c

Tags: c

```
CHAR fileBuffer[1000];
uint8_t tmpArray[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
uint8_t tmpArray2] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };


for (i = 0; i < sizeof(fileBuffer); i++)
    {
    printf("%02X ", (uint8_t)tmpArray[i]);
    }
```

take string from the file and convert to a byte array as in tmpArray. The string in the file would be like,
5FE1908F5FA463A9F94B8B1EA460B70A7D946B144E6A5093965A882E7855931A

I did try to read this into two byte arrays like this

```
memmove(tmpArray, fileBuffer, 32 * sizeof(uint8_t));
memmove(tmpArray2,fileBuffer[32], 32 *sizeof(uint8_t));
```

it copied in ok to tmpArray first 16bytes but the next 16bytes got messed up in tmpArray2.
If you could help with either way it would be great

string from file, string as above and convert to uint8_t arrays. the two separate arrays should result after reading/converting

```
uint8_t tmpArray[] = { 0x5F, 0xE1, 0x90, 0x8F, 0x5F, 0xA4, 0x63, 0xA9, 0xF9, 0x4B, 0x8B, 0x1E, 0xA4, 0x60, 0xB7, 0x0A };
uint8_t tmpArray2[] = { 0x7D, 0x94, 0x6B, 0x14, 0x4E, 0x6A, 0x50, 0x93, 0x96, 0x5A, 0x88, 0x2E, 0x78, 0x55, 0x93, 0x1A };
```

Comment: Have you tried to find a solution yet? Where is your attempted code? We won't do your work for you... and how does the input match with your desired output? They are not the same

Comment: its not code for you, pls try first and post your problem with code.

Comment: Does your .bin file contain a sequence of `'0'` and `'1'` characters as shown, or does it contain raw binary data?

Comment: How the combination of '1's and '0's can give you the zeroes only. Try a bit harder when you ask the questions.

Comment: Sorry, I tried this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you wanted? (to test give binary 01 combination as an first argument)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t charToBin(char c)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case '0': return 0;
        case '1': return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

uint8_t CstringToU8(const char * ptr)
{
    uint8_t value = 0;
    for(int i = 0; (ptr[i] != '\0') && (i<8); ++i)
    {
        value = (value<<1) | charToBin(ptr[i]);
    }
    return value;
}


int main(int argc,const char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n",CstringToU8(argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```

You can use CstringToU8() to convert 8 characters to one u8 number. Read whole data to char array (e.g. char * text) and then convert 8 characters to u8 number, store it and move you pointer 8 bytes further until array won't end.

Because after edit question was changed so here is my new solution. Code reading hex numbers from file and storing it into array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     FILE * fp;
    uint8_t number = 0;
    size_t fileSize = 0;
    uint8_t * array = NULL;
    size_t readedBytes = 0;
    size_t iterator = 0;

    fp = fopen ("hexNumbers.txt", "r");

    // check file size
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    /// allocate max possible array size = fileSize/2
    array = malloc(fileSize/2 * sizeof(uint8_t));

    /// read data into array
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        if (fscanf(fp,"%2hhx",&number) == 1)
        {
            array[readedBytes++] = number;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);


    /// print array output
    for (iterator=0; iterator<readedBytes; ++iterator)
    {
        printf("%02x ", array[iterator]);
    }

    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i tried this and i am getting errors, invalid operands to binary

Comment: question has been edited, to look for help in converting hexadecimal string into byte array